# Backbone model singleton

Tags: backbone.js

I am new to Backbone.js and I have the following problem: I have multiple views that uses the same model. I do not want to re-fetch model on every view render, but I want to fetch it only once and then when view is rendered use that instance/data.

My example: I have 3 views for user. One is some user statistics, another user info and third user profile. After login user lands on user profile view and there I fetch the user model but how could I then pass this model reference around or even better how could I access that model data from different views?

I hope I am not doing any anti-pattern here. I have seen a lot of examples with binding events to model change and then rerender all the views but that is not my case. I am using backbone.js with require.js and underscore template engine.

Comment: maybe post your code somewhere for someone to help u?

Comment: You can pass the same model into several different View constructors and be alright. Is something getting in the way of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the instantiated model:

```
define(function (require) {
    var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({})
    return new MyModel()
});
```